# Carregar JavaScripts na WebView Android KitKat

Tags: android

Tenho um app nativo com WebView onde carrego um conjunto de páginas com um `ViewPager`.

Para cada Page eu crio uma instância com WebView carregando um html via `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

Como dependo de alguns javascripts nas páginas, eu carrego assim `view.loadUrl("javascript:" + myJavaScriptFile)` no evento `onPageStarted` da
minha subclass da `WebViewClient`.

Dessa forma toda vez que um html é carregado no inicio eu já carrego os meus javascripts.

Resumindo a prosa tenho basicamente o Reader.

Tudo está funcionando nas versões 4.x enquanto meu `sdkTargetVersion = 14`.
Mas quando coloquei `sdkTargetVersion = 19` (kitkat) parou de funcionar todos os 
meus javascripts.

Já fiz tudo que estava neste link [Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Alguém tem alguma ideia pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir da API 19 o método `loadUrl`, não executa mais script e só deve ser utilizado para URL's.

Para essa finalidade foi adicionado ao [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) o método [`public void evaluateJavascript (String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback).`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Então para tornar as coisas mais transparentes, criei um [WebView de Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html), que já trata essa situação, segue código de minha solução:

```java
public class WebViewSupport extends WebView {

    public WebViewSupport(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WebViewSupport(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("javascript:")) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                String script = url.split("javascript:")[1];
                Log.i("WebViewSupport", "Script: " + script);
                evaluateJavascript(script, null);
                return;
            }
        }
        super.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Minha solução utiliza o mesmo conceito citado por [Eduardo Oliveira em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29134/2998).

Então você apenas necessita chamar o `loadUrl`, da mesma forma que chamava para versões antigas do Android, mantendo assim o mesmo código entre as versões. Algo similar a isso, por exemplo:

```java
String jsMethod = "doSomething()";    
webViewSupportInstance.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsMethod);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, mesmo já usando da forma do nosso colega Eduardo, este seu esquema funciona muito bem e elegante!! Vlw..

Answer (score 4):

Tente isso:

```
String jsMethod = "doSomething()";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webview.evaluateJavascript(jsMethod, null);
} else {
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsMethod);
}
```